# What replaces SD card in industrial applications

Tags: flash, sd, storage, industrial

I am using a SOM (something with Zynq 7000) that boots from an SD. While SD provides a lot of storage, i can't use it in industrial applications in a long term- it is not rated for temperature range and can come out because vibrations.

What storage could be used? I want comparable volume (0.5GB at least, the more the better) and preferably something not involving consumer grade connectos.

Comment: What temperature range do you need? You can get SD cards rated at -40~85°C (Kingston) and many of the sockets lock the card in. If they can be used reliably in a pro DSLR I would think they'd be fine in most applications.

Comment: What Spehro said and also does it need to be portable?

Comment: For really high temperature (>90-100C) you sometimes seem FRAM used instead of flash.

Comment: -40 to 85 is fine, but i can't guarantee what will the customer use. In fact, i am pretty sure they will use whatever is available an blame me if things happen.

Comment: Make sure your specifications include the minimum parameters for the cards.  You can't control customers, but you can mitigate liability.

Comment: Yes... I personally prefer not to go into mitigations. Same way i hate user agreements that no one reads :) i think, my customers will not read any of those limitations.

Answer (score 6):

SD cards are common in industrial applications.

There are industrial-grade SD cards. Quick search reveals that most of them are rated for operation -40°C to +85°C, eg. [Amtron](https://www.amtron.com/sd_card.htm).

When it comes to vibrations, there are vibration-resistant slots, like [this one](https://www.eenewseurope.com/news/vibration-resistant-automotive-sd-card-reader-features-push-lock-system) designed for automotive. Many (arguably most) SD slots are spring-locked, thus already resistant to vibration. That's because even for consumer devices vibration cannot be ruled out.

So unless your particular scenario presents unique challenges, SD card will work.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the fact that SD cards are actually available in a lot of temperature ranges I'd call "industrial", for devices where an vibration means that spring-fastened connectors won't do: eMMC, soldered to the board is pretty much a drop-in replacement, if your device supports both SD and eMMCs (and the Zynqs do, IIRC).

If you need interchangeability of storage media, but need to be vibration-resistant: tough problem. I'd guess my solution would probably be eMMC on a carrier board, connected via some appropriately rated connector (and/or secured using machine screws). Alternatives include booting from SPI flash (sloooow) and/or eMMC soldered onto the same board as the Zynq, and as soon as you have Linux (or even just uboot) running doing whatever your hardware supports: PCIe/NVMe, SATA or SAS (if you can load an FPGA image, why not?), USB, network...

Comment: Or hard-solder an eMMC to the board and have an SD slot to harvest data and/or update firmware.

Answer (score 3):

There are SMT devices that are SD card compatible; look for eMMC or iNAND.  A newer, similar technology is Universal Flash Storage (UFS).  Either of these might suit your needs.  [Here's a parametric search](https://www.mouser.com/Semiconductors/Memory-ICs/_/N-488qu?Keyword=iNAND&FS=True) that covers some of these devices.